# Clion + Cmake + Qt5 Error

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, clion

I have Clion IDE on Kubuntu 15.04. I have problem, when i build my application there is this problem :

```
/home/pierre/Bureau/CLion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/pierre/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/2a804d19/2a804d19/Debug --target WCPLauncher -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target WCPLauncher
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable WCPLauncher
/home/pierre/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.0.2: error adding symbols: Fichier dans un mauvais format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/WCPLauncher.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'WCPLauncher' failed
make[3]: *** [WCPLauncher] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/WCPLauncher.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/WCPLauncher.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/WCPLauncher.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/WCPLauncher.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'WCPLauncher' failed
make: *** [WCPLauncher] Error 2
```

This is my cmake.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(WCPLauncher)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(WCPLauncher ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package( Qt5Core REQUIRED )
find_package( Qt5Widgets REQUIRED )
find_package( Qt5Gui REQUIRED )

qt5_use_modules( WCPLauncher Core Widgets Gui )
```

Thanks !

Comment: Something is corrupted, unrelated to CMake or CLion.

Comment: Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Please post the output of `file /home/pierre/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.0.2`